# Microsoft OAuth - After sign in how do I get the user's email and display name?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-oauth

I'm adding Microsoft Authentication to Firebase. I'm able to login successfully but I need the user's email and display name. How can I fetch this? So far this is what I have.

```
export function* signInWithMicrosoft() {
  yield microsoftProvider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt: 'consent',
    tenant: 'consumers',
  });
  const res = yield signInWithPopup(auth, microsoftProvider);

  try {
    const credential = yield OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(res);
    const { accessToken, idToken } = credential;

    yield console.log(credential);
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of **Microsoft Graph API** to get signed-in user's email and display name by running below query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

To run the above query, you need to add **`User.Read`** permission in your Azure AD application like below:

[image]

As you already have **access token**, just modify your code to run **`GET`** request like below:

```js
export function* signInWithMicrosoft() {
  yield microsoftProvider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt: 'consent',
    tenant: 'consumers',
  });
  const res = yield signInWithPopup(auth, microsoftProvider);

  try {
    const credential = yield OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(res);
    const { accessToken, idToken } = credential;

    const response = yield fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });
    const data = yield response.json();
    const { displayName, mail } = data;

    yield console.log(displayName, mail);
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}
```

You can also decode the access token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) and check **`scp`** claim for permissions it has:

[image]

When I ran the same **`GET`** request in Postman by including Bearer token, I got **response** successfully with signed-in user's email and display name  like below:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been searching everywhere for this.